# ArrayOutOfBoundsException thrown when using Hash iterator

Tags: java, hash, iterator

I wrote my own Hash class, which I then used to store (String, LinkedList(String)) pairs as the (K,V) pairs. When i call the program to fill the hash, an ArrayOutOfBoundsException is thrown in the iterator. I have tried making the array much larger than needed, but still encounter the same error. The line where the error is thrown is "nodes[j++] = n;"

```
abstract class IteratorHelper<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    public DictionaryNode<K,V>[] nodes;
    protected int index;
    protected long modCheck;

    public IteratorHelper() {
        nodes = new DictionaryNode[currentSize];
        index = 0;
        int j = 0;
        modCheck = modCounter;
        System.out.println("int currentSize = " + currentSize);
        System.out.println("int tableSize = " + tableSize);
        for(int i=0; i<tableSize; i++)
            for(DictionaryNode n : list[i]) {
                System.out.println("int j = " + j);
                System.out.println("DictionaryNode key at nodes[" + j + "] = " + n.key);
                nodes[j++] = n;
            }
        nodes = (DictionaryNode<K,V>[]) Sorter.quickSort(nodes);
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(modCheck != modCounter)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        return index < currentSize;
    }

    public abstract E next();

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}

class KeyIteratorHelper<K> extends IteratorHelper<K> {

    public KeyIteratorHelper() {
        super();
    }

    public K next() {
        return (K) nodes[index++].key;
    }
}

class ValueIteratorHelper<V> extends IteratorHelper<V> {

    public ValueIteratorHelper() {
        super();
    }

    public V next() {
        return (V) nodes[index++].value;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why not 1) initialize `nodes` to be the correct size, or 2) make it out of a resizeable collection, such as `ArrayList`?

Comment: where are you creating the array "nodes" (not just declaration.)?

Comment: What is `currentSize`?

Comment: Think i might have figured it out. I was passing through the wrong size to the constructor of the hash in the program that fills it.Thanks for the responses!

Comment: You have omitted the definition of `list`, which is critical to the whole problem.